# Date Formatting in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to take in a date in 12H format and print it out in 24H format. Here's my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
        Date date = sdf.parse(str);
            System.out.println(sdf.format(date));


    }
```

I keep getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "07:05:45PM"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:12)
```

Comment: Spaces are important.

Comment: And the current `Locale`.

Comment: try {
            String now = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa").format(new java.util.Date().getTime());
            System.out.println("time in 12 hour format : " + now);
            SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
            SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            String time24 = outFormat.format(inFormat.parse(now));
            System.out.println("time in 24 hour format : " + time24);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }